# Do all SODIMM Rams have the size dimensions? (L x W x H)?

Tags: memory

planning to buy new ram..
but not sure if it would fit..

please help

not joking, i'm serious

My laptop supports up-to 8gb of ram..
So i want to upgrade.
But i'm confused if it would fit

Comment: What is your laptop model name and number?

Comment: HP 2000-2b43dx is the model name.

Answer (score 2):

No, all SODIMM's are not the exact same size, but are within a certain specific size standard as is listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM#General_characteristics). Size is typically not the main concern, the type (DDR, DDR2, DDR3, etc), speed, CAS, etc are more important.

Your main concern would be to find compatible RAM though, using any of various methods online to determine the correct ones, [Crucial's Advisory Tool](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/advisor?cm_re=top-nav-_-flyout-memory-_-us-memory-advisor), [Kingston's Find the right memory webpage](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/desktop-notebook), and [Newegg's Memory Finder](http://www.newegg.com/MemoryFinder/) would all be good places to start looking in conjunction with the documentation for your system.

Since you did not provide any specific information about the system you are attempting to upgrade, this is the best answer I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop supports the DDR3 1600 MHz 204 pin size SODIMM RAM.

Refer:

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/HewlettPackard20002b43dx.html